# How to save space with maps

Tags: java, memory, dictionary

I have to store large amounts of data in maps and the total size is critical.  The number of maps is high, the size of each individual map is small (<10 mappings for most of them) and the maps do not change after creation.

I see two ways (let's assume I know that *n* mappings will be stored):

1. Use a `HashMap` of initial size *n* and load factor 1
2. Use an `ArrayList` of size *n*, store (Key, Value) pairs.  Implement a `get()` method just as with Map

Is there a better way (maybe Guava `ImmutableMap`)?

Comment: Won't the data be taking up more space than the maps themselves?

Comment: In both cases the same data is stored, so there's no difference in terms of space.

In terms of time complexity the two approaches are the same, so I would think about code complexity instead of space. Focus on the logic and the implementation as in your case there's no much difference between the two approaches in terms of space/time complexity.

Comment: @MarounMaroun - I think the approach involving `HashMap` will probably take `O(1)` whereas the approach involving `ArrayList` will take `O(n)` in worst case because all the cells have to be checked for correct key when `get()` is called

Comment: @TheLostMind Getting from an `ArrayList` is O(1) as well.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm concerned about the additional buckets reserved by HashMap (25% by default). I'm really low on memory and the number of maps is really high. So that could make a difference. Access time is not the problem.

Comment: @TheLostMind: big-o performance is utterly irrelevant when n<10

Comment: @MarounMaroun - Yes, but then again he will have to check each cell right?.. Since he doesn't check via hashcode, he will have to check serially for the key right?

Comment: @TheLostMind, yes, and when there are less than 10 cells that is probably irrelevant for performance and could in some cases be faster than using a HashMap

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt - I completely agree.. I was just saying that the time complexity of the two approaches will not be same..

Comment: please define _large amounts of data_ more precise

Comment: @TheLostMind You are correct.. I misunderstood OP.

Answer (score 1):

See [**Perfect hash function**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function)

For a map where no longer keys are added, one could go for an optimized hash function: an array as small as feasible, and collisions with minimal influence.

Besides academical treatises out there, a hash function can be build from n different smaller functions/value entities, and an optimal can be found by trying a combination on the data set. And with varying array sizes.

As this area is too broad (like rehashing), search further, or do it yourself.

---

If you have gotten many values, taking the **same Object instance** instead of having many different Objects that are equal. This is done with an identity map `Map<T, T>` using only the first put key.

---

- A TreeMap is for large data as inefficient as a LinkedList w.r.t. ArrayList.
- The implementation of HashMap is quite interesting for efficiency. At the end one could do the same as `ArrayList.trimToSize()` though probably irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, and it's difficult to predict the space requirement exactly (depends on e.g. Java object overheads and packing, and the architecture you are on!). You may need to do some memory benchmarking with different approaches, using actual (or representative) data.

One way is to use pairs of arrays (one for keys, one for values).

Another idea is to use a single outer Map, but combine a key to address each inner map with the key for each inner value. This way, you avoid the overhead of lots of small Maps.

So for our first Map of:

```
"one" -> 1
"two" -> 2
```

and a second Map of

```
"three" -> 3
```

we store all the entries in a single Map, for example:

```
"1-one" -> 1
"1-two" -> 2
"2-three" -> 3
```

(You can probably use a similar idea using one large array or ArrayList, storing pairs of values, if you can store the pairs in a sorted manner so that you can find them efficiently using binary search). Or a pair of arrays/ArrayLists so you don't need to wrap key/value into a Pair object.

Answer (score 0):

If space is your primary concern, then using `ArrayList` or even plain arrays would be best. You'll have to test whether the serial lookup causes significant performance degradation; most likely it won't. If your data is `Comparable`, you could use a binary search, but I doubt whether that would actually help at such a small size.

One thing to be concerned about is whether you could sometimes have significantly larger maps; it might be a good idea to add a check and use a regular HashMap in that case.